# ViewPager inside a

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity that has a viewpager fragment in it

one of the pages has another viewpager fragment in it

the problem is, when i reach the page of the inner viewpager fragment, the "onCreateView" of the inner viewpager fragments doesnt get called, and so the page is blank.

Why is that ?

here is my code :

```
fragment_viewpager.xml
```

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

```
 fragment_viewpager_with_logo.xml
```

```
<include layout="@layout/logo" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {


private ViewPager fragmentPager;

private PagerAdapter fragmentAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container instanceof ViewPager) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewpager_with_logo, container, false);
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewpager, container, false);
}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            fragmentPager = (ViewPager)getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    fragmentPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
}

public void setAdapter(PurchaseFragmentStatePagerAdapter fragmentAdapter) {
    this.fragmentAdapter = fragmentAdapter;
}

public void setCurrentItem(int i) {
    fragmentPager.setCurrentItem(i);
}

public int getCurrentItem() {
    return fragmentPager.getCurrentItem();
}

public void setOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener l) {
    if (fragmentPager == null) {
        fragmentPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    }
    fragmentPager.setOnPageChangeListener(l);
}
```

}

in some activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container);
            MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter fragmentAdapter = new MyStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(settingsFragment);// settings
            ViewPagerFragment vpFragment = new ViewPagerFragment();
            fragments.add(vpFragment);
    fragmentAdapter.setFragments(fragments);
    fragmentPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);

            MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter innerFragmentAdapter = new   MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            List<Fragment> innerFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
             innerFragments.add(settingsFragment);
             innerFragmentAdapter.setFragments(innerFragments);
            vpFragment.setAdapter(innerFragmentAdapter);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.content_fragment, fragmentPager).commit();


}
```

MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
 public class MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private List<BaseFragment> fragments;

@Inject
public MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void setFragments(List<Fragment> fragments) {
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public BaseFragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments == null ? 0 : fragments.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the Fragment use `fragment.getChildFragmentManager()` in FragmentPagerAdapter's constructor instead of `getActivity().getFragmentManager()`